# Any possible way to stack Motor Driver shield L293D with Xbee Shield v03 on arduino?

Tags: shields, xbee, l293d

So i am trying to stack these two shield on arduino, now the problem here is that i guess there is a conflict between the pins of arduino being used by both shields, so can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: the XBee uses Serial on 0,1 (conflict with USB). the motor shield doesn't use the Serial pins. why do you think there is a conflict between shields?

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for both boards. They should list the pins used. Their associated libraries will define variables to which you can assign non-conflicting pins. Review the sample code provided as well. Usually, the sample code included setting the pins to use, even if the code only sets them to their default.

There is another possibility. I don’t think this is the case, but I’ve run into this issue with different shields. If the shields use I2C, they may need to have jumpers shorted to set an address.